# Average depending of parameter given

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I have a month parameter called `DimTiempoMes` So I when I run preview of report I select that month in combo box it can be from 1 to 12.

If I select 1 it return value of `Fields!InventarioDirecto_Monto.Value` of month 1

If I select 3 it return value of `Fields!InventarioDirecto_Monto.Value` of month 1,2 and 3 etc...

Now I want to get Average depending of selected `Fields!InventarioDirecto_Monto.Value`

For Example: If I select`DimTiempoMes`  with value`10`, formula will be for example:

`InventarioDirecto_Monto Value`      /        `DimTiempoMes.Value`

Execution:  `Sum(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`        /       `10`

So I try next expression:

```
=SUM(Fields!InventarioDirecto_Monto.Value) / CINT(replace(left(Split(Parameters!DimTiempoMes.Value,"[").GetValue(3),2),"]",""))
```

Problem is `SUM(Fields!InventarioDirecto_Monto.Value)`always come with sum of  12 months values, so it always sum values of 12 months

Question is, How can I get only values that `Fields!InventarioDirecto_Monto.Value` return depending of selected parameter `DimTiempoMes`?

Some Data:

[image]

In this image I have 3,719 in first column because I use DimTiempoMes as 1: so my colum Acum who have expression should be 3,719 too because `SUM(Fields!InventarioDirecto_Monto.Value)` equals to 3719 and divisor equals to 1 because I search 1. So 3,719/1 = 3791 and I getting 40,593

Other Example: if I use DimTiempoMes as 4

[image]

There I should get 3719 + 3639 + 3378 + 2999 / 4 = 3433.73 and I receive 10148

**Update:**

I also try adding custom code like:

```
Function Promedio(ByVal items As Object(),ByVal meses As Object(), ByVal Valor1 As integer) As Decimal
If items Is Nothing Then
Return Nothing
End If
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
suma = 0
For Each mes As Object In meses
IF CINT(mes) <= Valor1 
Then ct = 1
For Each item As Object In items
If (ct = CINT(mes))
Then suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
End If
ct += 1
Next
End If
Next
suma = suma/valor1
If (Valor1 = 0) Then return 0 else return suma
End Function
```

And Expression something like:

```
  =Code.Promedio(LookupSet(Fields!Dim_ConceptosInventario_.Value, Fields!Dim_ConceptosInventario_.Value, Fields!InventarioDirecto_Monto.Value, "DS_SubInventarioDirecto"),LookupSet(Fields!Dim_ConceptosInventario_.Value, Fields!Dim_ConceptosInventario_.Value, Fields!nPeriodo.Value, "DS_SubInventarioDirecto"),CINT(replace(left(Split(Parameters!DimTiempoMes.Value,"[").GetValue(3),2),"]","")) )
```

But I don´t get desire results

Comment: can you show some sample data and desired results?

Comment: I update my question with some examples of desire results  @Harry

Comment: Is there any possibility of skipping months? like value for Jan Feb Apr and May but not for March??